# Would it negatively affect performance writing "WHERE" on returned resultset from Table-Val. Function rather than on query itself?

Tags: sql-server, performance, user-defined-functions

I have an SQL Query in which currently returning the result set using Table-Valued Function as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetUserTable]
RETURNS @tblUser TABLE (
UserDeviceId BIGINT,
UserDeviceName NVARCHAR(50),
UserName NVARCHAR(50)
)

AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @tblUser 
Select Device.DeviceId, Device.DeviceName, User.UserName
FROM Device INNER JOIN User ON Device.DeviceId = User.UserDeviceId
RETURN
END
```

However, am filtering the returned resultset from the function as follows:

```
SELECT UserDeviceId, UserDeviceName, UserName
FROM [dbo].[fnGetUserTable]
WHERE UserName ='myuser@users.com'
```

Assuming, there are 1000,000 records in table User, what would be best practive, Performance wise, to filter the returned resultset from function as done in the previous example,
or to add the where condition directly into the SQL Query within the [dbo].[fnGetGoldRateTable] function as follow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetUserTable]
RETURNS @tblUser TABLE (
UserDeviceId BIGINT,
UserDeviceName NVARCHAR(50),
UserName NVARCHAR(50)
)

AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @tblUser 
Select Device.DeviceId, Device.DeviceName, User.UserName
FROM Device INNER JOIN User ON Device.DeviceId = User.UserDeviceId
WHERE UserName ='myuser@users.com'
RETURN
END
```

Or would it have same performance impact, since the SQL Server processes the From Clause before the Where Clause in a Select Query, which means the returned result set from the Function's Query would be Inserted by SQL Server into Temp table and then filtered according to the added where condition, in case of adding the Where condition in the function itself, which will lead to same performance criteria??

Please Advise,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why is that a function and not a view?

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft, well basically i pass parameters to it such as "@LangId" where accordingly the query shall return localized values, that's why it's a function, that's just a sample code, as the original query join 3 tables and returns results basically

Comment: Have you compared the query plan for the two options?

Answer (score 0):

One way to know is by comparing the two approaches by running each approach and take a look into the execution plan for each approach, find which one costs less and costs effective.

here is a reference to enable the execution plan

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

> what would be best practive, Performance wise, to filter the returned resultset from function as done in the previous example, or to add the where condition directly into the SQL Query

In this particular case adding the predicate inside the function is clearly better, as it would enable using an index on the column.

But that's because this is a multi-statement Table Valued Function, and those are "opaque" to the query optimizer (QO).  The logic inside the function is executed and the results returned to the outer query.  If this were an Inline Table-Valued Function, the case would be different.  That would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetUserTable] ()
RETURNS TABLE 
as
RETURN
    Select Device.DeviceId, Device.DeviceName, User.UserName
    FROM Device INNER JOIN [User] ON Device.DeviceId = User.UserDeviceId
```

And an Inline Table-Valued Function is parsed and folded into the query plan of the outer query, and the QO can optimize the whole thing.  And in particular it can "pushdown" query predicates from the outer query into the function.

So favor Inline Table-Valued Functions precisely because you don't have to add function parameters to get efficient query performance when filtering by one of the function's returned columns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as this had sufficient information, however i have the following inquiries, first isn't the function created in my example above considered Inline Table-valued function?? as i though since it returns a table it's already an inline table valued function?? Second, do i understand clearly that with inline table-valued function i don't have to pass the "where condition criteria" as parameters to the function, just adding these criteria to outer query would be sufficient and would'nt affect performance negatively?? Thanks for your help

Comment: Your function is not an inline TVF because it declares the return table and inserts into it.  It doesn't matter if the the TVF only actually has one statement, it's still not an inline TVF.  And yes with an inline TVF you can typically apply the predicate in the outer query and let the QO figure it out.